# How to show or where to find session/registration controller for devise token auth gem in RAILS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-token-auth

I want to do something in the session controller when the user is using the sign_in method. Where to find the session sign_in controller for devise token auth gem in rails? Or is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to create it yourself. Here's how to do it: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-controllers

Comment: It's not the devise gem. I am using devise token auth gem.